# State updates by itself in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build a small quiz app in React using jservice.io

However, I can't find a solution for this problem: after I fetch random question in `updateQuestion()`, somehow, data fetches again (or changes in some other way) when I call `checkAnswer()`, even though it's not needed and not called.

The code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");
const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");


useEffect(() => {
updateQuestion()
}, [])


async function updateQuestion () {
  await fetch(`http://jservice.io/api/random`)
.then(data => data = data.json())
.then(function (response) {
   setQuestion(response[0].question)
   setAnswer(response[0].answer)
   console.log("fetched")
} )
const title = document.querySelector(".question_title")
title.innerText = question


console.log(`${question} - when update question`) 
console.log(`${answer} - when update question`)
}

function checkAnswer () {
console.log(`${question} - when check answer`) 
console.log(`${answer} - when check answer`)
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? `data = data.json()`. It should be `data.json()` no?

Comment: based on what you are showing it should not be the case that data fetched twice, can you show more of your code? maybe the place where you are calling checkAnswer()

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without seeing how you are calling `checkAnswer` or a valid code example.  However, I've tried to reproduce what I presume is a [comparable example](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-breeze-2oyoy?file=/src/App.js) that works as I believe you expect it should:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");

  function updateQuestion() {
    // Fake fetch
    new Promise(resolve => {
      const data = [
        {
          answer: "to winnow",
          question: "To sift through material \u0026 toss out the junk"
        }
      ];
      resolve(data[0]);
    }).then(response => {
      setQuestion(response.question);
      setAnswer(response.answer);
    });

    console.log(`${question} - when update question`);
    console.log(`${answer} - when update question`);
  }

  function checkAnswer() {
    console.log(`${question} - when check answer`);
    console.log(`${answer} - when check answer`);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("calling useEffect");
    updateQuestion();
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{question}</h1>
      <p>{answer}</p>
      <button onClick={() => checkAnswer()}>Click Me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you need more information, we're going to need more code. :)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

You triggered it yourself because useEffect is triggered at least twice:

> you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

So it triggers once at componentDidMount, then once again at componentDidUpdate

Comment: useEffect should only be called twice here if the state if added to the dependency array.